# Memoize functions with `Ord` arguments in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there a common Haskell idiom for memoizing recursive functions with type

```
Ord a => a -> SomeType
```

In particular, I have a recursive function with type

```
(Int, Int, [Int]) -> Int
```

that I want to memoize.

Comment: Have you looked at the [data-memocombinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators-0.3) or [MemoTrie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie) libraries or the [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization) on memoization?

Comment: @bheklilr I had looked at the Haskell wiki, however from the little that I understand of the wiki, I am not sure how to translate to the general `Ord` case as it did not seem clear how I would order the keys in a list, or how the trie would be structured for a general `Ord` type.

Comment: `Ord` isn't enough information to build a pure memoization tree from. For the code to be pure, the structure of the data must be known a priori so that the lazy structure in memory doesn't need to change as the results of computations are discovered, as doing so would be a side effect. For monadic memoization, `Ord` is sufficient; it allows you to discover the structure as computations are carried out, allowing you to build e.g. a `Map`.

Answer (score 3):

Your data type

```
(Int, Int, [Int])
```

can be mapped onto `Integer`. The first 2 `Int`s are just a bunch of bits, and the list of `Int`s is just a list of bits, coming in bunches at a time. Since it's possible to make a memoization tree for an `Integer`, it's possible to make a memoization tree for this data type. The [memo-trie package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie) agrees, providing the following 3 relevant instances:

```
instance HasTrie Int
instance HasTrie x => HasTrie [x]
instance (HasTrie a, HasTrie b, HasTrie c) => HasTrie (a, b, c)
```